# Alternative to text-align-last of safari?

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

[Apparently](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last) none of Safari browsers support `text-align-last` -property. Is there any neat alternative(non-js) without redrawing `select` to achieve the same result? 
Particularly desired result: centered text of selected value in full-width `select`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a slight work around for this using text-indent, it requires some javascript code if you want it perfectly centered or you can hard code it for some padding.

Text-align-last (if supported by the browser) will overwrite the text-indent value.